# Deploying Node.js API to Internet via IIS

Tags: node.js, iis

I keep getting this error, but I have done the following, but no work, the node.js API can't be accessed via https://www.xyz.site/api/ in the internet but can access with http://localhost:3001/ in the Azure server, I need the api be accessed in the internet, can anyone pls help.

1. Enable full permission of IIS USERS/the specific application users to the
   folder permission
2. Set loggingEnabled to false
3. iisreset command
4. Set reverse proxy to http://localhost:3001/, when user access the api

> iisnode encountered an error when processing the request.
>
> HRESULT: 0x2 HTTP status: 500 HTTP subStatus: 1001 HTTP reason:
> Internal Server Error You are receiving this HTTP 200 response because
> system.webServer/iisnode/@devErrorsEnabled configuration setting is
> 'true'.
>
> In addition to the log of stdout and stderr of the node.exe process,
> consider using debugging and ETW traces to further diagnose the
> problem.
>
> The node.exe process has not written any information to stderr or
> iisnode was unable to capture this information. Frequent reason is
> that the iisnode module is unable to create a log file to capture
> stdout and stderr output from node.exe. Please check that the identity
> of the IIS application pool running the node.js application has read
> and write access permissions to the directory on the server where the
> node.js application is located. Alternatively you can disable logging
> by setting system.webServer/iisnode/@loggingEnabled element of
> web.config to 'false'.

Comment: I just changed to use pm2 to host the node app, it works in localhost but when proxy with a dummy site in iis , it still get 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied(https://www.somesite.com/someAPI/). Can anyone please advise

Comment: You need to start from scratch with HttpPlatformHandler, https://halfblood.pro/running-nodejs-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/ IISNode has been out of maintenance for a very long time.

Comment: Please enable detailed error messages in IIS, Sub Status codes can give you more direct insight into why you're receiving a 403 error. Please tell us what substatus code you see in the application log, if any.